# reassign localStorage on start page

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I'm setting current language and current country with localStorage

I need to set the current country with localStorage, due to the fact that the same languages are listed in different countries

similar to that on http://abb.com

It works fine, for selecting the current language and the current country
But for the start page, I'd like to reassign the language to "Swedish" and the country to "Sweden"
Right now, if the last language selected was Hungary - Hungarian, then when I reopen the site, or navigate to the start page, the localStorage sets Hungary - Hungarian instead of Swedish Sweden

I'd like to somehow clear the localStorage when revisiting the site, if the root of the site is .com, not a language specific url

How do I do this?

Here is the code so far:

```
jQuery('.ui-tabs-panel .country a').click(function(){
        var selectCountry = jQuery(this).siblings('span').text();
        var selectLanguage = jQuery(this).text();

        if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            localStorage.setItem("countryname", selectCountry);
            localStorage.setItem("languagename", selectLanguage);
        } else {
            console.log('Sorry! No Web Storage support..');
        }

    });

    jQuery('.mysite-language').text(currentLangVal);
    jQuery('.mysite-country').text(localStorage.getItem("countryname"));
    jQuery('.mysite-language').text(localStorage.getItem("languagename"));
```

I tried doing something like

if window.location.path is less than one (meaning we're on the start page)
then set l`ocalStorage.countryname = "Sweden"`
and `localStorage.languagename = "Swedish"`

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you almost had it there, except it's not `window.location.path` but `window.location.pathname`, and it's not "less than one", but `== '/'`. So:

```
if(window.location.pathname == '/') {
    // Set language to Swedish
} else {
    // Keep the current language
}
```